# What is a word that would best fit in this sentence?

Tags: style, word-choice

The Harlem Renaissance has changed America in a ________ way.

I'm trying to make the sentence sound professional. Here is what I had at first: The Harlem Renaissance has changed America in a great way. But it doesn't sound like something a professional writer would write.

For those who don't know, the Harlem Renaissance was a great time in American history. The Harlem Renaissance was an artistic flowering of the “New Negro” movement as its participants celebrated their African heritage and embraced self-expression, rejecting long-standing—and often degrading—stereotypes.

Comment: I would recommend considering an adjective with more precision.  Greatness could indicate depth of the change, the permanence of it, the wide-ranging influence, even before you got into the details of what it changed.

Comment: *I'm trying to make the sentence sound professional.*  What does that mean?  What are, or would be, the attributes of a *professional sentence*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

The Harlem Renaissance changed America in an exemplary way by changing the perception of African- Americans.

Some other words that might be good to consider:

- Desirable
- Admirable
- Pleasant

Answer (score 0):

In a project-specific way.

There is no perfect answer to this, because I can't know what you want to say about the Harlem renaissance. Do you want to say it was inspirational? That it undermined White cultural assumptions? That later problems undermined the Harlem renaissance? Or just it was super-cool?

Decide what your goal with the project is, and what impact you want it to have. Then you can pick the perfect word. So then the Harlem renaissance will have changed a bit of America in a literary way.

Answer (score 0):

Transformative,immersive, or perhaps even,auspicious. 
The choice is dependant on your thesis statement.
The term "enveloping" may add the particular nuance you're reaching for?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).